# Integrate $\int_0^3 \int_0^{\sqrt{9-x^2}}\int_0^{\sqrt{81-x^2-y^2}}(1) dzdydx $

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

How to integrate using cylindrical coordinates the following function?

$$\int_0^3 \int_0^{\sqrt{9-x^2}}\int_0^{\sqrt{81-x^2-y^2}}(1) dzdydx $$

My problem is not with the function itself but with arranging the respective boundaries with the variables.

Is it correct $\int_0^3 \int_0^{\sqrt{9-x^2}}\int_0^{\sqrt{81-x^2-y^2}}(1) dzdydx  \Rightarrow   \int_0^3 \int_0^{\sqrt{9-r^2cos^2\theta}}\int_0^{\sqrt{81-r^2}}(1) r dzd\theta dr $

When I got to the integration I got very confused, as I mentioned, with my arrangement of the boundaries and the change in area $dzd\theta dr $ since that in the second integral $\int_0^\sqrt{9-r^2cos^2\theta}$ I repeat the variable $r$. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Thanks Denis, drawing a picture helps a lot, specially with the xy-plane. I think got the idea from your example. The radius is easy to get, it goes from 0 to 3. Now I see the semi-circle, since it's $\sqrt{9-x^2}$ then it comes from $y^2+x^2=3^2$ and it's a semi-circe with radius 3 centered in the origin. Now, for the triple integral, since z in cartesian coordinates is z in cylindrical, the whole thing is $\int_0^{\pi} \int^3_0 r \int_0^{81-r^2} dz dr d \theta $

Answer (score 1):

The boundary is a cylinder with a cap, that lies on the first octant. The projection on the $x$-$y$ plane is the positive part of $\frac14$ of a circle with radius $3$ (lying on the first quadrant). How do you find such area using polar coordinates?

$$A=\int_0^{3}\int_0^{\sqrt{9-x^{2}}}dxdy=\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\int_0^3rdrd\theta.$$

On the other hand, to find the upperbound of $z$, simply recall that $x^2+y^2=r^2$, so:

$$\begin{cases}
z=\sqrt{81-(x^2+y^2)}\\
x^2+y^2=r^2
\end{cases}
\implies z=\sqrt{81-r^2}$$

therefore, yielding

$$\begin{aligned}V&=\int_0^3\int_0^{\sqrt{9-x^2}}\int_0^{\sqrt{81-x^2-y^2}}dzdydx=\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\int_0^3\int_0^{\sqrt{81-r^2}}rdzdrd\theta\\&=\frac{\pi}{2}\int_0^3r\sqrt{81-r^2}drd\theta=-\frac\pi2\frac{1}{3} \left(81-r^2\right)^{3/2}\Big|_0^3=\frac{9}{2} \left(27-16 \sqrt{2}\right) \pi
\end{aligned}$$

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer and the comment, the geometric visualization helped a lot. Just one thing, why it only goes from 0 to $\pi /2$ and not all the way to $\pi$?

Comment: @PaulinaMora Solo un par de peque;as notas: la "tapa" del cilindro es parte de la esfera $\;x^2+y^2+z^2=81\;$, y los límites de $\;\theta\;$  son de cero a $\;\pi/2\;$ pues estamos en el primer octante. Fíjate que $\;x\;$ está entre $\;0\;$ y $\;3\;$, y el límite de $\;y\;$  está entre cero y el semicírculos superior  $\;x^2+y^2=9\;$  en el plano $\;xy\;$

Comment: @PaulinaMora Traza un círculo de radio 3 en un plano $\;xy\;$ . Como $\;0\le x\le 3\;$ , eso te dice que solo trabajaremos en el primer cuadrante. Que $\;0\le y\le \sqrt{9-x^2}\;$ nos dice que estamos entre el eje $\;x\;$ y el semicírculo superior ( o sea, $\;y\ge 0\;$) . Esto que acabo de describir es la proyección del cuerpo tridimensional nuestro en el plano $\;xy\;$. Procura siempre hacer un pequeño diagrama del lo que se te pide. Un poco de geometría analítica y mucha práctica te ayudarán.